# Why does Visual Studio replace my message with something else?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

When I try to display a long message with emoji and line breaks, Visual Studio deletes my message and replaces it with

```cs
resources.GetString("MyMessage.Text")
```

For example I wrote this:

```cs
this.txtMessageLongOrder.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
this.txtMessageLongOrder.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.txtMessageLongOrder.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
this.txtMessageOrder.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Menu;
this.txtMessageOrder.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 19);
this.txtMessageOrder.Name = "txtMessageOrder";
this.txtMessageOrder.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(279, 504);
this.txtMessageOrder.TabIndex = 2;
this.txtMessageOrder.Text = " Last name\n First name\n Age\n Address\n City\n Zip code\n Occupation\n Hobbies\n Eye color\n Hair color \n etc...\n etc...";
```

Then Visual Studio turns it into:

```cs
this.txtMessageOrder.Text = resources.GetString("txtMessageOrder.Text");
```

I need to keep the message in plain text in the code so I can make changes...

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Why are you writing the form code by hand? You're not supposed to manually edit the `InitializeComponent()` function, unless you know exactly what you're doing. VS will automatically update/change it next time you open the designer.

Comment: It looks like translatable values are moved to a resources file, where you can edit them (and possibly translate)